# Multiple expect declorations with the same expected output

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm testing the function `shopify.formatRequestUrl` below and each time I'm expecting that the output of the function is going to be the same. Is there any way to make this more DRY?

```
expect(shopify.formatRequestUrl("shop"))
  .equal("https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json")

expect(shopify.formatRequestUrl("/shop"))
  .equal("https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json")

expect(shopify.formatRequestUrl("/shop/"))
  .equal("https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json")

expect(shopify.formatRequestUrl("shop.json"))
  .equal("https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json")

expect(shopify.formatRequestUrl("/admin/shop"))
  .equal("https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json")

expect(shopify.formatRequestUrl("/admin/shop.json"))
  .equal("https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json")
```

Something like this: *psudo code*

```
expectAll[
  shopify.formatRequestUrl("shop"),
  shopify.formatRequestUrl("/shop"),
  shopify.formatRequestUrl("/shop/"),
  shopify.formatRequestUrl("shop.json"),
  shopify.formatRequestUrl("/admin/shop"),
  shopify.formatRequestUrl("/admin/shop.json")
]
  .equal("https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json")
```

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using underscore and looping over an object of all the arguments works.

```
_.each([
  "shop",
  "/shop",
  "/shop/",
  "shop/",
  "shop.json",
  "/shop.json",
  "/shop.json/",
  "shop.json/",
  "/admin/shop",
  "/admin/shop/",
  "/admin/shop.json",
  "/admin/shop.json/",
  "admin/shop.json/",
], function(result){
  expect(shopify.formatRequestUrl(result))
    .equal("https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json")
})
```